# Selecting rows or columns with data.table R?

Tags: r, select, row, data.table

Imagine I have a data.table, for example:

```
library(data.table) 
RRR <-data.table(1:15,runif(15),rgeom(15,0.5),rbinom(15,2,0.5))

    V1      V2    V3  V4
 1:  1 0.33577273  0  0
 2:  2 0.66739739  2  1
 3:  3 0.07501655  0  0
 4:  4 0.43195663  2  1
 5:  5 0.39525841  3  2
 6:  6 0.15189738  1  1
 7:  7 0.02637279  0  1
 8:  8 0.44165623  0  1
 9:  9 0.98710570  2  0
10: 10 0.62402805  1  0
11: 11 0.84829465  3  2
12: 12 0.02170976  0  1
13: 13 0.74608925  0  2
14: 14 0.29102296  2  0
15: 15 0.83820646  1  1
```

How can I get a data.table from it, with all the ROWS that contain a "0" at any column?  (or some value)

If I had to do it with a single column I could use:

```
RRR[V4==0,]

   V1    V2      V3  V4
1:  1 0.33577273  0  0
2:  3 0.07501655  0  0
3:  9 0.98710570  2  0
4: 10 0.62402805  1  0
5: 14 0.29102296  2  0
```

But what if I want to do it with all the columns at once because I have many?

This doesn't do what I need.

```
RRR[,sapply(RRR,function(xx)(xx==0)), with=TRUE]   

     V1      V2     V3    V4
[1,]  FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[7,]  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[8,]  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[9,]  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[11,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[12,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[13,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[14,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[15,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Maybe with a for loop and some complicated paste?.
Though, I would prefer to use simple data.table syntax.

Similarly, how would you get a data.table with all the COLUMNS that contain a  '0'  at any row?

I know how to get the columns (as a whole) that fulfills a condition, such as being numeric,

```
RRR[,sapply(RRR,function(xx)is.numeric(xx)),with=FALSE]
```

but this method doesn't work if I want to test the condition elementwise.

In case anybody is interested, this is the system.time() for a bigger random data.table  with the different solutions you provided so far, with slight modifications.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000000
RRR <- data.table(matrix(rgeom(100*n,0.5), ncol=100))

Getting ROWS   
> RRR[RRR[,rowSums(RRR==0)>0]] 
   user  system elapsed 
   2.72    0.55    3.27 
> RRR[rowSums(RRR==0)>0] 
   user  system elapsed 
   2.58    0.70    3.28 
> RRR[apply(RRR,MAR=1,function(xx)any(xx==0))]
   user  system elapsed 
   10.81    0.19   11.00       
> RRR[apply(RRR[,paste0('V',1:ncol(RRR)),with=FALSE],function(xx)any(xx==0),MAR=1)]
  user  system elapsed 
  10.49    0.30   10.83 

Getting COLUMNS
> RRR[,sapply(RRR,function(xx)any(xx==0)), with=FALSE] 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.81    0.31    1.12 
> `[.listof`(RRR,colSums(RRR==0)>0) 
   user  system elapsed 
   2.14    0.27    2.41 
> RRR[,colSums(RRR==0)>0, with=FALSE] 
   user  system elapsed 
   2.26    0.48    2.75 
> RRR[, .SD, .SDcols=sapply(RRR, function(x) any(x==0))]      #only version 1.9.5, seems the same solution than the first one.
   user  system elapsed 
   0.78    0.36    1.14 
> RRR[, .SD, .SDcols=sapply(RRR, function(x) any(!as.logical(x)))]
   user  system elapsed 
   0.41    0.25    0.66 
> RRR[Reduce('|',lapply(RRR,function(xx)(xx==0)))]
   user  system elapsed 
   3.11    0.33    3.44 
> RRR[,apply(RRR[,paste0('V',1:ncol(RRR)),with=FALSE],function(xx)any(xx==0),MAR=2),with=FALSE]
   user  system elapsed 
   3.48    0.80    4.28
```

I haven't included yet:

```
RRR[, i := any(unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) x==0))), seq_len(nrow(RRR))][i==TRUE][,i:=NULL]
```

It took several minutes and I stopped it, and it "tags" the rows instead of extracting them and it's the most complex solution.

I'll wait for faster or simpler solutions and hear your comments and likings.

sapply was supposed to be slower but it isn't.
The results could change if the data.table contains other kind of data.

We could speed it up if we can stop the test (==0) as soon as the first occurrence happens within every row or column.  But I guess we can't do it without loops or some low level access or bitwise operation.

I've thought of a new method.

1. sapply(RRR,function(xx)which(xx==0))
2. I need to combine the results of a) with a union of the lists, but I don't know how to do it for any number of columns.
3. And then get that rows  RRR["a)"]

I guess it's gonna be much slower if the number of zeroes is big.

Maybe also try `RRR[unique(unlist(sapply(RRR,function(xx)which(xx==0))))]`
but it's too slow.

An option to get the opposite would be `RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA; na.omit(RRR)`

Comment: Updated with timings

Comment: nice to see timings, I've added another one, not sure but maybe `as.logical` will be faster than `==`.

Comment: Yes, you are right: for some reason my `Reduce` approach does produce different results. By the way, one way to check this (for the "Getting ROWS" operation) is to just compare the selected rows: `myrows1 <- RRR[RRR[,rowSums(RRR==0)>0],.I]`, `myrows2 <- RRR[rowSums(RRR==0)>0,.I]`, and so on. You can compare these using the `identical` and `setdiff` functions. (It seems fairly standard to verify using `identical` after comparing timings.)

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, I think it was said (by @BrodieG) that `apply` would be slower for row-selection than `rowSums` (not `sapply` related to column-selection). The test there would be `system.time(RRR[apply(RRR,1,function(x)any(!x))])`. I find this takes 6x as long as `system.time(RRR[rowSums(!RRR)>0] )`, so he's right.

Comment: What about a sapply version for the ROWS selection?. I'm not able to do it.

Comment: Jan's answer is an `sapply` answer, in a sense, since `sapply` is the same as `unlist(lapply())` in this case. Try `RRR[RRR[,any(sapply(.SD,function(x)!x)),by=1:nrow(RRR)]$V1]`

Comment: Frank, I've got to fix your Reduce approach. 
RRR[Reduce(`|`,lapply(RRR,`!`))]
or the general way: RRR[Reduce('|',lapply(RRR,function(xx)(xx==0)))]

Comment: Ah, nice fix! By the way, the `Reduce` one is for rows (but you've put it under columns above).

Comment: The `as.logical` for columns does not work on 1.9.4, but I can see that that is fastest. The more important step is the selection of columns rather than how you use the selection to subset `RRR`, I suspect. For example, the `as.logical` approach also works here: ```res <-  `[.listof`(RRR,sapply(RRR, function(x) any(!as.logical(x))))```

Comment: Any solution with melt + dcast ?

Comment: What about something like  na.omit(RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA).  I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `rowSums` function can be used here:

```
RRR[rowSums(!RRR)>0]
```

**How it works:** `!RRR` is a matrix with `TRUE` at any zero. In the general case, you can replace `!RRR` with whatever logical condition you want to check. For example, to see if any element is equal to `3`, you could take the `rowSums` of `RRR==3`.

I think `rowSums(test(x))>0` is essentially the same as `apply(RRR,1,function(x)any(!test(x)))`; both coerce the object to a matrix. I find the `rowSums` version easier to read and think I've heard people praise its efficiency.

---

For columns, similarly:

```
RRR[, colSums(!RRR)>0, with=FALSE]
```

Comment: Your solution works but only if the value you are trying to match is zero.  How would you do it in general?
(for values such as  7, NA or "food")

Comment: What is that  `[.listof`  ?

Comment: The `[.listof` command is an obscure command that I found by typing ```methods(`[`,data.table)```. It works with any type of list, including data.tables and data.frames. I feel like it should be listed on `class(RRR)`, but it is not. It can be verified with `is.list(RRR)`.

Comment: I've given another example besides checking for zeros.

Comment: `rowSums` is waaaaaay faster than anything involving `apply`.  There will be a coersion to matrix, but it isn't obvious to me that the entire OP workflow can't be done in matrix, in which case there would be no conversion.  Also, I think Arun mentioned he was working on something like `rowSums` for `data.table`.

Comment: @Frank thanks for `[.listof`, I will definitely use it!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this.

```
library(data.table) 
RRR <-data.table(1:15,runif(15),rgeom(15,0.5),rbinom(15,2,0.5))
RRR[, i := any(unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) x==0))), seq_len(nrow(RRR))
    ][i==TRUE
      ][,i:=NULL]
```

Extending answer for the second part of question.

```
 RRR[, .SD, .SDcols=sapply(RRR, function(x) any(x==0))]
 # you may add this one also to timing, I wonder how it will work
 RRR[, .SD, .SDcols=sapply(RRR, function(x) any(!as.logical(x)))]
```

`.SDcols` as logical vector was introduced quite recently so be sure to update your data.table first.

Comment: Jan, I've tried but I get the error, ".SDcols should be column numbers or names".  And my data.table version is  1.9.4  (on Windows).

I'm timing the different options.

Comment: @skan CRAN version cannot be considered as recent version, this is the case for every robustly developed package. Go [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) and [travis](https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis/) and you will have the bests of two worlds. If you are not convinced then just read the [1.9.5 news/readme](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table).

Comment: OK, it was not easy because of incompatibility problems but now I have data.table 1.9.5 installed.   Timings are almost identicall and now your code works.

Comment: Jan Gorecki I've updated the first post with your last code, it's faster, though only useful to test zeroes.  What advantages do you find using ".SDcols"?

Comment: Making code statement more dynamic, `.SDcols` simply defines columns provided as character, integer or logical. Only selected columns will be included in `.SD` data.table object to operate on.