# omitting NA values with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, na

How can I get this to work?

```
library(data.table) 
RRR <-data.table(1:15,runif(15),rgeom(15,0.5),rbinom(15,2,0.5))

na.omit(RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA)
```

I want to replace some values (here those ==0) by NA.  And then remove that rows.

Or if you want to run benchmarks you can use a larger data.table:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000000
RRR <- data.table(matrix(rgeom(100*n,0.5), ncol=100))
```

This question is related to:
[Selecting rows or columns with data.table R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811601/selecting-rows-or-columns-with-data-table-r)

I've just realized that the question I've posted here is just the opposite to the one I posted last day (getting the rows with zeroes vs getting the rows without any zero) and that could be confusing for some people.

Anyway, I'll continue with the question as is, remove the rows with zeroes, i.e. try to fix my example that uses na.omit().

Here are your contributions

```
na.omit(RRR[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, which(x==0), NA))])  ##akrun
user  system elapsed 
 2.12    0.17    2.31 

{ RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA; na.omit(RRR) }   ##Frank
user  system elapsed 
 6.67    0.86    7.55    

{ for(j in 1:ncol(RRR)){ set(RRR, i=which(RRR[[j]]==0), j=j, value=NA)  } ;  na.omit(RRR) }  ##akrun
user  system elapsed 
  1.62    0.28    1.91 

RRR[, indx := as.logical(rowSums(.SD == 0))][(indx)]   ## David
user  system elapsed 
 2.89    0.36    3.25
```

The fastest is akrun loop (maybe could be improved with some apply instead), but it modifies the original data. The easiest and maybe the one that better replies to my question is Franks suggestion { RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA; na.omit(RRR) })

Comment: Try `na.omit(RRR[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, which(x==0), NA))])` or `for(j in 1:ncol(RRR)){ set(RRR, i=which(RRR[[j]]==0), j=j, value=NA)};  na.omit(RRR)`

Comment: Why would you replace with `NA`s and then remove? Can't you just remove the ones with the zeroes in the first places? For example, `RRR[, indx := !rowSums(.SD == 0)][(indx)]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  That is what I thought too..

Comment: @akrun I wonder which method will be more efficient though.

Comment: @DavidArenburg If there are many columns/rows, may be the `set`, (not benchmarked), BTW, the `rowSums` approach is good, but is it efficient as it converts to matrix?

Comment: @akrun yeah that's what I meant, though I think `.SD == 0` is already a logical matrix.

Comment: I just wanted to try the na.omit approach to see if it's faster, and it's written very compactly

Comment: @akrun you should post your stuff before someone steals it, as it seems this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Your code is very fast.

Comment: David, your code does the opposite I've asked, it should be RRR[, indx := !!(rowSums(.SD == 0))][(indx)]

Comment: @David Arenburg Do you mean I'm trying to steal akrun idea?  I will vote the one that i consider the best answer, and also consider other's votes.

Comment: Have no idea what you talking about. Did I ever mention you? You have got it all wrong.

Comment: " you should post your stuff before someone steals it, as it seems this is what the OP is looking for". Maybe you meant someone else. If so I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I meant that some other user will post akruns answer as it's own. It happens a lot around here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try either

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(RRR[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, which(x==0), NA))])
```

Or using `set`

```
for(j in 1:ncol(RRR)){
      set(RRR, i=which(RRR[[j]]==0), j=j, value=NA)
}
 na.omit(RRR)
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000000
RRR <- data.table(matrix(rgeom(100*n,0.5), ncol=100))
RRR1 <- copy(RRR)
RRR2 <- copy(RRR)
RRR3 <- copy(RRR)

system.time({RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA
             na.omit(RRR)})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  5.713   0.000   5.155 


system.time(na.omit(RRR1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, 
        which(x==0), NA))]))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #  3.000   0.000   2.337 

system.time({
 for(j in 1:ncol(RRR2)){
     set(RRR2, i=which(RRR2[[j]]==0), j=j, value=NA)
   }
  na.omit(RRR2)
  })

 # user  system elapsed 
 #  2.466   0.000   2.025 

##DavidArenburg's code from comments
 system.time(RRR3[, indx := !rowSums(.SD == 0)][(indx)])
 # user  system elapsed 
 #  0.000   0.000   2.796
```

Comment: Fyi, the OP posted some benchmarks in a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29811601/1191259

Comment: @Frank Thanks, it means `rowSums/rowMeans` are faster, the `set` based approach was not in the list.

Comment: Tell me how to include that code inside a system.time() and I'll update the benchmarks.  Any alternative to create a function with all the code?

Anyway, I don't like that it modifies the original data.  But it's interesting.

Comment: @skan I think if you replace `na.omit` with `complete.cases`, it may be even faster.

Comment: @akrun , could you write the solution with the complete.cases, please?
I will update the benchmark of the old question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811601/selecting-rows-or-columns-with-data-table-r  (with much larger data). 
I didn't know you could include a whole code inside the system.time.

Comment: @skan Yes, I will update it.  You could include a whole code or use it as a function i.e. `f1 <- function() {na.omit(RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA)}; system.time(f1())`

Comment: On my computer the last one runs fastest, which isn't too surprising. The others are held back by having to do the unnecessary conversion-to-NA thing (the only difference from the linked question).

Comment: You timed "na.omit(RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA)" , my first code, but I think it doesn't work.

Comment: @Frank I also thought so

Comment: @skan Did you mean the output is not correct or the system.time not correct?  In the `set` method, you could replace the `na.omit` step with `RRR[RRR[,complete.cases(.SD)]]`

Comment: @akrun, if it's not too much bothering you, I invite you to use a bigger data.table data.  for example  the same than in my old post.   set.seed(1)
n <- 1000000
RRR <- data.table(matrix(rgeom(100*n,0.5), ncol=100))

Comment: The output for that one isn't correct. It should be written as `RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA; na.omit(RRR)`

Comment: @akrun  I mean the output is not correct in my computer.  it says: logical(0)
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 1
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

Comment: @skan I didn't check the output of your code.  Try what Frank suggested.

Comment: @skan It also means that if there is a single NA in one of the columns for a row, that row will be deleted.  I think all the rows in that example have at least a single NA.

Comment: Oh, good point. It's motivated by matrix subsetting, which I cannot figure out a way of applying to a data.table, so...`mmm <- as.matrix(RRR); mmm[(mmm==0)] <- NA; na.omit(data.table(mmm))`. Should be quite slow :)

Comment: @Frank please post your solution "RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA; na.omit(RRR)" as a whole Answer in order to get my votes.

Comment: What about using your "set" solution with an apply instead of a "for loop" ?

Comment: @skan Never seen anybody using `apply` with `set`.  Based on the `?set`, the examples are all using `for`.  What is the problem with `for` loop?

Comment: No problem. I've just just seen many times the suggestion "avoid using loops, they are slow".

Comment: OK, I choose your answer.  Frank's could be more related to what I wanted (though finally he mixed it with matrixes) but yours is more elaborated and faster.

Comment: @skan  A properly constructed `for` loop is as fast as `apply` family solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an inefficient approach that makes sense if you know base R:

```
mmm <- as.matrix(RRR)
mmm[(mmm==0)] <- NA
na.omit(data.table(mmm))
```

As far as I know, the matrix-style subsetting done on the second line (matching a line in the OP) requires conversion to a matrix.

---

**Efficiency.** My answer takes twice as long as @akrun's using `set`.

Approaches like these -- that are constrained to follow the pattern (1) replace by `NA`  (2) select rows by `na.omit` -- perform worse than simply selecting rows directly (the topic of the OP's [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29811601/1191259)). This is shown by the timing for @DavidArenburg's code (copied here from @akrun's answer): `RRR[, indx := !rowSums(.SD == 0)][(indx)]`. Because we are comparing against zero, this can be made a little faster with `!.SD` in place of `.SD==0`.

Comment: @skan Okay, I have made this into an answer. If you're tempted to use this approach, you might want to consider just using matrices (not `data.table`s) for your current project. Going back and forth (as I do here) is quite inefficient.

Comment: I've tried directly using data.tables   RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA; na.omit(RRR)  and I think the result is still a data.table.  I've checked it with class().
I'm just trying to learn to use the data.table package because I've read (and I think) it's fast and powerful

Comment: @skan You can compare the results of doing that with the other approaches to see if they are producing the same result. I'm not sure what `RRR[(RRR==0)] <- NA` does, but suspect it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Converting to a matrix is usually considered inefficient. This is the main issue with the `row/col/Sums/Means` family